# Developing custom functions in Postgres using Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Say I have a big composite formula to compute the quality of a widget

```
quality = 0.4(factory_quality) + 0.3(1/days_since_manufacture) + 0.3(materials_quality)
```

Each of these three factors are functions themselves, which require joins to the factories table, and maybe to a bill of materials join table with materials, where the associated records are averaged or something or other.

Architecturally, how would you manage this in a Rails project? What's the best practice to a) produce the correct query and b) manage the code in Rails?

Currently for the sql, I'm using a subquery in the FROM statement:

```
SELECT *,
  (0.4 * factory_quality + 0.3 * (1/days_since_manufacture) + 0.3 * materials_quality) AS quality
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    ((factories.last_inspection_score + factories.variance_score)/2) AS factory_quality,
    (now() - widgets.created_at) AS days_since_manufacture,
    SUM(materials.quality_score) AS materials_quality
  FROM widgets,
  JOIN factories ON widget.factory_id = factories.id
  JOIN bills_of_materials ON widget.id = bills_of_materials.widget_id
  JOIN materials ON bills_of_materials.material_id = materials.id
  GROUP BY widgets.id
) AS widgets;
```

In rails, I have this implemented mostly using ActiveRecord:

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :factory
  has_many :bills_of_material
  has_many :materials, through :bills_of_material

  class << self
    def with_quality
      select([
        "widgets.*",
        "(0.4 * factory_quality + 0.3 * (1/days_since_manufacture) + 0.3 * materials_quality) AS quality"
      ].join(",")
      .from("(#{subquery}) AS widgets")
    end
    private
      def subquery
        select([
          "widgets.*",
          "((factories.last_inspection_score + factories.variance_score)/2) AS factory_quality",
          "(now() - widgets.created_at) AS days_since_manufacture",
          "SUM(materials.quality_score) AS materials_quality"
        ].join(","))
        .joins(:factory,:materials)
        .group("widgets.id")
        .to_sql
      end
  end
end
```

That said, I feel like I could make this a custom function in Postgres, move all this sql in to that function, migrate it, and clean up the rails to look like

```
def with_scores
  select("*,quality_score_func(id) AS quality")
end
```

or something to that effect, but I feel like it will be a pain in the ass to manage what will be an evolving formula through database migrations, not to mention somewhat of a task to find out what the current form of the formula is (and also difficult to test).

How have other people solved this problem? Any tips or suggestions?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not trying to avoid sql, and I believe the calculation belongs in the database for performance reasons. I'm just wondering if anyone has developed a design pattern to clean this code up.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the least SQL-ly way I could think of to do this. I couldn't really test this, but hopefully it's a helpful exercise at least. As I understand it, if you use `includes`, Rails will put together the joins and eager load all the relevant data in one query.

```
# All of these are additional Widget instance methods; you decide if they are private
#
# Example use:
#
#   @widget = Widget.includes(:factory, :materials).find(1)
#   puts @widget.quality_score
# or
#   @widgets = Widget.includes(:factory, :materials).all
#   @widgets.each { |widget| puts widget.quality_score }

# Consider making these weights named constants
def quality_score
  0.4 * factory_quality + \
  0.3 * (1/days_since_manufacture) + \
  0.3 * (materials_quality_score )
end

def days_since_manufacture
  Time.now - created_at
end

def factory_quality
  (factory.last_inspection_score + factory.variance_score)/2
end

def materials_quality_score
  materials.inject(0) {|sum, material| sum + material.quality_score }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I'm not really looking to do more of the work in Ruby, quite the opposite. If I do the calculation in Ruby, yes the code will be cleaner, but in order to do queries like Top 5 by quality I will need to instantiate all records, calculate for all records, sort in memory, then discard N - 5. I am willing to live with code ugliness to avoid that performance hit, but I feel like this must be a common enough problem that there might be a less ugly way than I've done it.

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding. If that's the case I agree defining a Postgres function is a bad idea. Instead I think I would define Ruby methods that generate the appropriate snippets and compose those into something you can send to `find_by_sql`. I don't expect this will look that much better, but it allows you to separate out calculations that might change from the blocking and tackling.